# why should I use NYQ(Nyquist Frequency) to get the propoer value of the cutting frequency in high or low pass filter?

Tags: signal, signal-processing, digital-filter

I am working on signal processing using filters (basic,IIR,FIR) but I didn't quite got the intuition behind the next operation when I am performing a high pass filter with the cut frequency defined as highcutoff:

```
nyq = 0.5 * fs  # Nyquist Frequency
normal_cut=f_highcutoff/nyq
```

why should we perform this and use the normal_cut as the cut frequency ?

Comment: You'll need to provide some context around that second line.

Comment: also, come on, at least write out the name of the filter in the title.

Comment: Ask an answerable question. Be sensible and not expect people to 2nd guess what it is you don't understand. This is a Q and A site. Answers require questions and you haven't asked a valid one for this site.

Comment: Sorry Guys I edited the question I hope it is clear now?

Comment: You didn't fix the title as prompted.

Comment: Ok, now I'm completely confused. You changed the title, so I don't understand it anymore. What's a "NYQ"?

Comment: My Bad Sorry I was refering to Nyquist Frequency

Comment: In continuous time systems, the frequency varies from zero to infinity and it is visualised as lying on a straight line. In discrete time systems, the frequency can take on values from 0 to some maximum value. If we know the sampling frequency, this maximum value can be calculated as half the Nyquist frequency. But different softwares can take input in different formats. Some take frequency input as being from zero to \$\pi\$ (frequency lies on a circle). Other software takes **input as a fraction of Nyquist frequency**; i.e. from zero to one. Check the documentation of the software you use.

Answer (score 1):

It is completely dependent on the specific software used.

In continuous time systems, the frequency varies from zero to infinity and it is visualised as lying on a straight line.

In discrete time systems, the frequency can take on values from *0 to some maximum value*. If we know the sampling frequency, this maximum value can be calculated as half the Nyquist frequency.

But different softwares can take input in different formats. Some take frequency input as being from zero to π (frequency visualised as lying on a circle). Other software takes input as **a fraction of Nyquist frequency**; i.e. from zero to one.

In short, check the documentation of the software you use. Some require input to be between zero and one. Hence the division by the Nyquist frequency.

Comment: Yes I am using python and they require that even if I still uses Nyquist frequency

Comment: The documentation says "*Wn: A scalar or length-2 sequence giving the critical frequencies. For digital filters, **Wn are in the same units as fs. By default, fs is 2 half-cycles/sample, so these are normalized from 0 to 1**, where 1 is the Nyquist frequency. (Wn is thus in half-cycles / sample.) For analog filters, Wn is an angular frequency (e.g., rad/s).*" From [Documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.iirfilter.html#scipy.signal.iirfilter).

Comment: For [FIR filters](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.firwin.html#scipy.signal.firwin), they say "*frequencies in cutoff should be positive and monotonically increasing between 0 and fs/2.*" and "*fs :The sampling frequency of the signal. Each frequency in cutoff must be between 0 and fs/2. Default is 2.*".